# Laravel resource routing in subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, routes

There are a lot of questions like this, but I don't find exactly what I ask.

So, I want to use resource routing, but in subfolder.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'adm', 'prefix' => 'adm'], function () {
    Route::resource('users', 'Adm\UserController');  
});
```

In this case, all actions without params works fine (index and create), but if I go to `/adm/users/show/1` I got error `NotFoundHttpException`

Looks like it needs route vars in response manually, because if I don't use subfolder (adm) it works fine. What I'm doing wrong?

I want to use resource routing because there will be many controllers like users, projects, prices, rooms etc with standard CRUD actions.

Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(`GET`) `/adm/users/show/1` is not a route provided by your `users` resource controller.  `show` is the Controller method, but does not appear in the URL:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

You're after (`GET`) `/adm/users/1`.

There is no problem using resource routes in subdirectories, as long as you watch out for conflicting routes.

Comment: It was so easy?) Thanks a lot!